# Is FAMD (Factor Analysis of Mixed Data) truly a factor analysis technique? or it is a dimension reduction technique?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, latent-variable

PCA is distinct from factor analysis; it's a dimension reduction technique. PCA does not account for individual variable noise. On the other hand, FAMD (Factor Analysis of Mixed Data) combines PCA and MCA without incorporating a stochastic term for each variable. Despite its name, FAMD seems more like a dimension reduction technique than factor analysis. It seems to me that when the goal is to extract latent variables, modeling noise independently of the factors is essential.

However, I can't find an alternative to FAMD for mixed data. Is FAMD truly the optimal tool for this task? If I want to estimate the factor-independent noise for each variable, what are my options?